# How to work with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Set<String>` which I want to convert to `Map<String, List<NameAndType>`, where each entry in my source list is key for each entry and the value is computed using an expensive function.

```
Set<String> allTables = getAllTablesInternal();
allTables.parallelStream().<...?>
```

There is a `expensive_function` which returns a `List<NameAndType>` given a `tableName` (String). What I want to do is write a collect function which will collect to a Map.

Comment: What should be the value associated to each key?

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question. each of the tableName (each element of the set)

Comment: I'm talking about the value. How should the value be computed given a `List<NameAndType>`?

Comment: I shouldn't have used the map function. Peter understood my question and I got my answer.

Comment: the community is really brutal. You down vote my question just because I couldn't word it correctly. I have edited it again to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use toMap

```
Map<String, List<NameAndType>> map = 
            allTables.parallelStream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> expensive_function(k)));
```

Comment: How can you answer when there's not even a question? What's lookupTable and how is it correlated with expensive_function?

Comment: @Tunaki I am assuming the question is; "How [get this] to work with Java 8 Streams?"

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: That's precisely what I needed.

Comment: @Tunaki You are right about `expensive_function` you can't be too sure how smart people are. ;)